# How to define dynamic variable in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, dynamic

I would like to have a shell variable that could be dynamically run every time it is refered, for example, i would like to have a variable $countPwd which could return the count of files/dirs in the current directory, it could be defined as:

```
countPwd=`ls | wc -l`
```

and if I do `echo $countPwd` it would only show the value when I define the variable, but it won't update automatically when I change my current directory. So how do I define such a variable in bash that the value of it get updated/calculated on the fly?

Update:
The $PWD is a perfect example of a variable get evaluated in the real time. You don't need to use $() or backticks `` to evaluate it. How is it defined in bash?

Comment: Write a cover function for `cd` that sets the variable when you have changed directory.  Or create a script or function (perhaps `fc` for 'file count') and simply use that (less typing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a function:

```
countPwd() {
    ls | wc -l
}
```

Then call the function like any other command:

```
echo "There are $(countPwd) files in the current directory."
```

Comment: but that's not a variable, so I still can't do echo $countPwd. In another word, I would like to have a variable similar to the $PWD in bash. The $PWD is a perfect example of a variable get evaluated in the real time. How is it defined?

Comment: PWD is a "sell variable"; somehow a «builtin». Also it is not evaluated in real time, it is set by the cd command (as per what bash's man page says). IMHO the workaround proposed using a bash function is quite good (+1)

Comment: @hmontoliu Thanks. I guess your explaination about cd command solve the mystery, then I guess John's answer is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: store the command in a variable, and evaluate it when required:

```
countPwd='ls | wc -l'
echo $(eval "$countPwd")
```

Comment: -1 [Really terrible idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). I know you can't go wrong with a number, but if someone changes the value of `countPwd` you're SOL.

Comment: @l0b0 You can make countPwd readonly to alleviate that concern.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write some C code: write a bash's [loadable buitins](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/examples/loadables/README?id=bash-4.2) to do the heavy lifting in defining variables with dynamic values like `$SECONDS` or `$RANDOM` (`$PWD` is just set by `cd`).

More details in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878487/7988067) (a duplicate of this question).

Comment: If there is a good duplicate, then this question should be closed as duplicate. But at least you spent the time to really answer this question.