# How to create a bash variable like $RANDOM

Tags: linux, bash

I'm interest in some thing : every time I `echo $RANDOM` , the show value difference . I guess the RANDOM is special (When I read it , it may call a function , set a variable flag and return the RANDOM number . ) . I want to create a variable like this , how I can do it ？ Every answer will be helpful .

Comment: Yes, it's special. Such variable can only be created by modifying Bash's source code.

Comment: Try `$func(){do something}` then call `$func`

Comment: I can't do it with `$func`, but can `func` . My bash version is 4.2.53(1).

Comment: @LinuxLiker : you are correct, the `$` is not a valid character for a function name. just use `func`. If you need that value in a variable, the put it there with `myVar=$(func)`. Good luck.

Comment: What is your exact requirement? Maybe you can have any general variable & its value can be set via [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) (Applies for interactive shells only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special behavior of `$RANDOM` is a built-in feature of bash. There is no mechanism for defining your own special variables.

You can write a function that prints a different value each time it's called, and then invoke it as `$(func)`. For example:

```
now() {
    date +%s
}

echo $(now)
```

Or you can set `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to a command that updates a specified variable. It runs just before printing each prompt.

```
i=0
PROMPT_COMMAND='((i++))'
```

This doesn't work in a script (since no prompt is printed), and it imposes an overhead whether you refer to the variable or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are BASH scripting there is a $RANDOM variable already internal to BASH.
This post explains the random variable $RANDOM:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

It generates a number from  0 - 32767.

If you want to do different things then something like this:

```
case $RANDOM in
[1-10000])
  Message="All is quiet."
  ;;
[10001-20000])
  Message="Start thinking about cleaning out some stuff.  There's a partition that is $space % full."
  ;;
[20001-32627])
  Message="Better hurry with that new disk...  One partition is $space % full."
  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this question a while ago and wasn't satisfied by the accepted answer: He wanted to create a variable just like `$RANDOM` (a variable with a dynamic value), thus I've wondered if we can do it without modifying `bash` itself.

Variables like `$RANDOM` are defined internally by bash using the `dynamic_value` field of the [`struct variable`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.h#n82). If we don't want to patch `bash` to add our custom "dynamic values" variables, we still have few other alternatives.

An obscure feature of `bash` is [loadable builtins](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/examples/loadables/README?id=bash-4.2) (shell builtins loaded at runtime), providing a convenient way to dynamically load new symbols via the `enable` function:

```
$ enable --help|grep '\-f'
enable: enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [name ...]
      -f        Load builtin NAME from shared object FILENAME
      -d        Remove a builtin loaded with -f
```

We now have to write a loadable builtin providing the functions (written in C) that we want use as `dynamic_value` for our variables, then setting the `dynamic_value` field of our variables with a pointer to the chosen functions.

The production-ready way of doing this is using an another loadable builtin crafted on purpose to do the heavy-lifting, but one may abuse `gdb` if the `ptrace` call is available to do the same.

I've made [a little demo](https://github.com/plcp/bashful) using `gdb`, answering *"How to create a bash variable like `$RANDOM`?"*:

```
$ ./bashful RANDOM dynamic head -c 8 /dev/urandom > /dev/null
$ echo $RANDOM
L-{Sgf
```